# How can I separate a scanned text to its letters?

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I am looking for a simple way to recognize musical  Unicode text (written in byzantine musical notation). My idea is to compare each musical symbol with the scanned text and find all the coordinates(of the surrounding box)  of this symbol in the scanned text. My basic problem is that `TextRecognize` does not takes in account these symbols. The second answer In [textrecognize not up to pa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916732/mathematicas-textrecognize-not-up-to-pa)

suggest the use of the command  `ImageCorrelate`. Also `Highlightimage` is another good  candidate. Both commands find all the occurrences of a template(in my case of a letter) in the scanned image. But I don’t know how to use these commands to extract some useful information that will help me recognize the text. Could you please give some ideas? For testing purposes I upload three different  letters the [image: ison](U+1D046) the [image: oligon](U+1D047) and [image: apostrofos] (U+1D051) plus a random piece of musical [image: text] in .jpg format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but it's too extensive to be a comment. Here's a good way to get all of the components using the wonderful `MorphologicalComponents`, paired with `ChanVeseBinarize`:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXlxu.jpg"];

binarized =
  ChanVeseBinarize@img;

components =
  MorphologicalComponents[binarized];

componentNumbers = Rest@Sort[DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@components];

slices =
  Table[
   ImageCrop@
    Image[Map[If[# == i, 0., 1.] &] /@ components,
     "Real", ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"],
   {i, componentNumbers[[;; 100]]}
   ];
```

Then we can see the effect of this:

```
Partition[slices, 10] // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image: char grid]

Note that we could get bounding boxes instead by supplying `Method->"BoundingBox"` to `MorphologicalComponents`.

Hope this is enough to get you started.

#### On getting image coordinates

We can slightly modify the code that generated our `slices` to also get the coordinate bbox:

```
slices =
  Table[
   With[{component = Map[If[# == i, 0., 1.] &] /@ components},
    ImageCrop@
      Image[component, "Real", ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"] ->
     CoordinateBoundingBox@Position[component, 0.]
    ],
   {i, componentNumbers[[;; 100]]}
   ];
```

This way each image is paired with its coordinate bounding box. Then we can operate on the images themselves to figure out which ones are the same. This'll take a tiny bit more work, but shouldn't be bad at this point as the component images are of pretty high quality already.

#### On getting matching images

So `ImageDistance` seems to ID the images pretty well if you use the `"EarthMoverDistance"`. I'm sure this could be played with more to make it more solid though.

Here's what I found from a quick survey:

Start by importing your test images and prepping them:

```
chars =
  ImageCrop@*
    ColorNegate@*ChanVeseBinarize@*Import /@ {
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVqDd.jpg",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uci9a.jpg",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LtJm.jpg"
    };
```

Then the general form will be:

```
KeySort@GroupBy[
  Select[slices,
   ImageDistance[First@#, chars[[i]],
      DistanceFunction -> "EarthMoverDistance"] < <dissimilarity-max> &
   ],
  ImageDistance[First@#, chars[[i]],
    DistanceFunction -> "EarthMoverDistance"] &
  ]
```

And here .05 seems to work pretty well for `<dissimilarity-max>` although you'll want to tune this. By pre-processing the pulled slice images (filling in gaps and whatnot using, e.g. [`Dilation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dilation.html)) you can improve this matching process yet further.

#### Using ImageDimensions as a criterion

As each of these characters has a pretty unique size to it we can use the `ImageDimensions` as matching criteria (to scale this we could use the `ImageDimensions` ratio).

```
distanceFunctions[im1_, im2_] :=
  {
   Norm[ImageDimensions@im1 - ImageDimensions@im2],
   ImageDistance[im1, chars[[1]],
    DistanceFunction -> "EarthMoverDistance"]
   };

matches =
 Table[
  KeySort@GroupBy[
    Select[slices,
     And @@ MapThread[
        # < #2 &, {
         distanceFunctions[First@#, chars[[i]]],
         {15, 1}
         }] &
     ],
    Last@distanceFunctions[First@#, chars[[i]]] &
    ],
  {i, Length@chars}]
```

This is near perfect (note that we're not really using the `ImageDistance` but we could tune the factors for each match so I'm leaving it in there).

Comment: @MB 1965 the command MorphologicalComponents  is indeed very good. I would like also to have the actual coordinates of these components in the text. Is  it possible?

Comment: Sure. Where I generate those slices, use Position  instead / as well.

Comment: Could you please give the code? I cant understand  how I will generate all the positions in  which the first element slices[[1]] (for example) does appears ...In others words at which positions of the text  the (   could  be found?

Comment: Yeah, by the way I don't think the answer is worth accepting as it is. Leave the question open in case someone else can do it better.

Comment: I have not  tested the last code yet but I am sure it works very well. If you have time please enter some pre-processing techniques. I think that one must have much experience with Dilation or other Image Processing commands for good results. I am  newbie   on this topic ...Thank you!

Comment: Actually I realized there's an even better way. We'll use the fact that each of these shapes has a rather unique image size. I think using that and tweaking the match parameters is all you need at this point. No preprocessing necessary (Although I have to say I have minimal experience with all of this so I'm sure you could get it pretty quick. Just started picking it up in January.)